# Android layout change

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use different layout for landscape and portrait. I have put the xml files in layout and layout-land respectvely.

For my parent activity i've set android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" so i want to handle orientation changes myself.

I've tried this to manually change the layout:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FoodDashboardFragment()).commit();
}
```

It works ... but the app crashes when going to home screen ... so .. i'm guessing i'm missing something. Is there another (simple) way of doing this?

Here is the log:

```
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FoodDashboardFragment{41a06e30} is not currently in the FragmentManager
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.putFragment(FragmentManager.java:546)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.restauranthanovra.MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MainActivity.java:167)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1137)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1215)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:2951)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3010)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1222)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-23 17:58:46.717: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the logcat of the crash

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, instead of using `onConfigurationChanged`, make use of `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle)` and save any data that needs to be retained into the `Bundle`.

This way, when the Activity is destroyed and recreated, your land-layout will automatically be used and you retain data that you only need.

The use of `onConfigurationChanged` is generally for specific/special cases and in most cases, `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` is suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but, as i said, i need to keep my parent activity intact, so i'm using android:configChanges="orientation".

Answer (score 0):

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` if you have fragments hierarchy. eg. if you have fragments pager in you parent fragment.